# How to fix pixelated background-image on Chromium-based browsers?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, chromium

On Chromium-based browsers, downscaled images used as `background-image` are pixelated while they look more blurred when displayed with an `<img>` tag. **Is there a way to change the render style of a background image so it look like the display in the tag?** I tried the [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Image-rendering) property but it doesn't seem to work on `background-image`. It looks fine on Firefox.

Example of render on Brave, left is `background-image` and right is with the `<img>` tag:

[image: img and background-image comparaison]

```css
#backgroundImage, img {
  width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#backgroundImage {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundImage"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png" />
```

Comment: What you thinks about your question “its technological implementation differs?
Or is it tied to whatever browser's base, no?” In my opinion, its technological implementation different.

Comment: @DSDmark Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question. I noticed this rendering behaviour on Brave, Electron and Egde, which all use Chromium, but not on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be happening only when both the `size:cover` and `position:center` rules are applying. You can have the same result in the `<img>` by changing its `object-fit` to `cover`:

```css
#backgroundImage, img {
  width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#backgroundImage {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundImage"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png" />
```

So to avoid it, you can replace the `background-size:cover` rule with `100% 100%`:

```css
#backgroundImage, img {
  width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#backgroundImage {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundImage"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EfB.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had not thought that it could come from the other properties. However, in my case it doesn't really solve the problem because `background-size: 100% 100%;` is different from `cover` and it will change the aspect ratio of the image. I managed to get inconsistent renderings by removing `background-repeat`, it changes evey time I reload. Changing size and position (which I can't do) seems to affect `.png` and `.jpg` differently... I wish I could find a way that work for every images every time.

Comment: @Arkellys I thought you wanted the same behavior as your <img>. `background-size: 100% 100%;` is what your <img> is currently applying.

Comment: Sorry if my question is misleading. On my question I used a small image as an example to show the problem. I want to get the same display quality as the img tag but I can't change the background size and position properties.

Comment: I also want to point out that changing `background-size: 100% 100%;` doesn't work on Electron, so I suppose it also depends on the browser/app.

Comment: Then raise an issue at https://crbug.com so that they change their behavior. Not much we can give you if you can't change anything from what you have.

Comment: Yeah, I will accept your answer because even though it doesn't solve my particualr case it does solve my initial question. Thanks.